# Hibernate Embeded columns gives null value

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch data from hibernate I have following Entity with Embeded class.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "new_reconnect_pts1", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "carrier_id", "bonus_criterion", "start_date", "end_date" }))
public class NewReconnectPts1 implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4181934462782746103L;
    private NewReconnectPts1Id id;

    public NewReconnectPts1() {
    }

    public NewReconnectPts1(NewReconnectPts1Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "carrierId", column = @Column(name = "carrier_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "bonusPts", column = @Column(name = "bonus_pts", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "bonusCriterion", column = @Column(name = "bonus_criterion", nullable = false, length = 20)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "cat", column = @Column(name = "cat", length = 20)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "customerType", column = @Column(name = "customer_type", nullable = false, length = 20)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "startDate", column = @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false, length = 3080)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "endDate", column = @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false, length = 3080)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "duration", column = @Column(name = "duration", nullable = false, length = 1)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "remarks", column = @Column(name = "remarks", length = 30)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "expiryDate", column = @Column(name = "expiry_date", nullable = false, length = 3080)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "noOfTrans", column = @Column(name = "no_of_trans")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "contractId", column = @Column(name = "contract_id")) })
    public NewReconnectPts1Id getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(NewReconnectPts1Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Embeded Class**

```
@Embeddable
public class NewReconnectPts1Id  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int carrierId;
     private int bonusPts;
     private String bonusCriterion;
     private String cat;
     private String customerType;
     private Date startDate;
     private Date endDate;
     private char duration;
     private String remarks;
     private Date expiryDate;
     private Integer noOfTrans;
     private Integer contractId;

    public NewReconnectPts1Id() {
    }


    public NewReconnectPts1Id(int carrierId, int bonusPts, String bonusCriterion, String customerType, Date startDate, Date endDate, char duration, Date expiryDate) {
        this.carrierId = carrierId;
        this.bonusPts = bonusPts;
        this.bonusCriterion = bonusCriterion;
        this.customerType = customerType;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
    public NewReconnectPts1Id(int carrierId, int bonusPts, String bonusCriterion, String cat, String customerType, Date startDate, Date endDate, char duration, String remarks, Date expiryDate, Integer noOfTrans, Integer contractId) {
       this.carrierId = carrierId;
       this.bonusPts = bonusPts;
       this.bonusCriterion = bonusCriterion;
       this.cat = cat;
       this.customerType = customerType;
       this.startDate = startDate;
       this.endDate = endDate;
       this.duration = duration;
       this.remarks = remarks;
       this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
       this.noOfTrans = noOfTrans;
       this.contractId = contractId;
    }


    @Column(name="carrier_id", nullable=false)
    public int getCarrierId() {
        return this.carrierId;
    }

    public void setCarrierId(int carrierId) {
        this.carrierId = carrierId;
    }

    @Column(name="bonus_pts", nullable=false)
    public int getBonusPts() {
        return this.bonusPts;
    }

    public void setBonusPts(int bonusPts) {
        this.bonusPts = bonusPts;
    }

    @Column(name="bonus_criterion", nullable=false, length=20)
    public String getBonusCriterion() {
        return this.bonusCriterion;
    }

    public void setBonusCriterion(String bonusCriterion) {
        this.bonusCriterion = bonusCriterion;
    }

    @Column(name="cat", length=20)
    public String getCat() {
        return this.cat;
    }

    public void setCat(String cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    @Column(name="customer_type", nullable=false, length=20)
    public String getCustomerType() {
        return this.customerType;
    }

    public void setCustomerType(String customerType) {
        this.customerType = customerType;
    }

    @Column(name="start_date", nullable=false, length=3080)
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Column(name="end_date", nullable=false, length=3080)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Column(name="duration", nullable=false, length=1)
    public char getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(char duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Column(name="remarks", length=30)
    public String getRemarks() {
        return this.remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    @Column(name="expiry_date", nullable=false, length=3080)
    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return this.expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    @Column(name="no_of_trans")
    public Integer getNoOfTrans() {
        return this.noOfTrans;
    }

    public void setNoOfTrans(Integer noOfTrans) {
        this.noOfTrans = noOfTrans;
    }

    @Column(name="contract_id")
    public Integer getContractId() {
        return this.contractId;
    }

    public void setContractId(Integer contractId) {
        this.contractId = contractId;
    }
```

when i execute the program i gets following hibernate query

```
select newreconne0_.carrier_id as col_0_0_, newreconne0_.bonus_pts as col_0_1_, newreconne0_.bonus_criterion as col_0_2_, newreconne0_.cat as col_0_3_, newreconne0_.customer_type as col_0_4_, newreconne0_.start_date as col_0_5_, newreconne0_.end_date as col_0_6_, newreconne0_.duration as col_0_7_, newreconne0_.remarks as col_0_8_, newreconne0_.expiry_date as col_0_9_, newreconne0_.no_of_trans as col_0_10_, newreconne0_.contract_id as col_0_11_ from new_reconnect_pts1 newreconne0_
```

which gives me result when i fire the same through Client.but when i checks the list returned by Hibernate it gives me the `Collection` which has has the no. of rows with every field as `null`

please help

Answer (score 0):

try hql. something like

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from NewReconnectPts1Id);
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: use hql editor to check whether the object returns value or not.if it returns value then maybe it has a problem in your code.